# Export Xcode Project from Xamarin Project

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am developing apps on Xamarin. Currently I am developing an app for iOS.

For deployment I have to pass the source code to the customer as an Xcode project.

Is there any way to export a Xcode project from the Xamarin project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No. Xamarin does not trans-compile to ObjC/Swift so there is no conversion  from a `.Net`-based `.sln`/`.csproj` to an Xcode `.xcodeproj`/`.xcworkspace` that would be using ObjJ and/or Swift. You *could* share `.storyboard` and `.xibs` if you are using them, but thats about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way right now to do what you ask, unlike Unity3D that exports a library ,  Xamarin provides an ipa at the end of the compilation.
You can recycle your storyboards and make a porting of yours .cs to .swift or .h .m .

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to do that, you can just keep all your storyboard from your iOS project and include it in the Xamarin iOS  project. The class name are really closed so you can traduct all the project file by file by following the Xamarin iOS structure.
Hope it helps :)